# java long Division two values unexpected result

Tags: java, output, long-integer, division, primitive-types

```
public class LongDivision {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long a = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
        final long b = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        System.out.println(a/b);
    }
}
```

Output of this code block is :5 why the result is five?

Comment: non-floating literal values are of type int. Your multiplication therefore overflows. Use `L` to specify your literal values as long.

Comment: right, I understand to have to use A literal. But beside I wonder that how java calculate the division result as five. what is mathematical operation background of this or algorithm

Comment: `24*60*60*1000*1000` equals `86 400 000 000` or roughly 86 billion. An integer overflows at `2 147 483 647` or roughly 2.1 billion. The overflow just happens to get you a value that is equal to `5*24*60*60*1000`.

Comment: 2^31 is roughly 2.1 billion but 5*24*60*60*1000 is equal 432 million the result is too small than int max value so if this is overflows problems why not 24*60*60*1000* ??[6,7,8.. until non owerflow] thanks your interest  :)

Comment: @yasin `24*60*60*1000*1000 = 86,400,000,000`. In Binary, it is ‭`0001 0100 0001 1101 1101 0111 0110 0000 0000 0000‬`. Since the literal values are of type integer, only the 32 LSB will be taken. the overflow will be discarded. So the value would be `0001 1101 1101 0111 0110 0000 0000 0000`, which is `500,654,080` in decimal. So this would be your a value. Your b value is 86,400,000. No overflows. So now `500,654,080/86,400,000` is 5.

Comment: @AshwinKKumar thanks your detailed and logical explanation.

Comment: @yasin I have posted my explanation as an answer. In case someone in the future has the same question!

Answer (score 3):

Each of your factors is an `int`, and the multiplication overflows. Even though you've declared the result as a `long`, the intermediate products are all `int`s because their factors are `int`s.

If you declare the first factor as a `long` (by using the suffix `L`), it'll work as expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final long a = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
    final long b = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    System.out.println(a/b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000` overflows and results in `500654080` instead of expected `86400000000`.

`24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000` works as expected.

Comment: How to calculate the value of 50065408 why is not 60065408 or other the value also is small than int max size

Answer (score 0):

`24*60*60*1000*1000 = 86,400,000,000`. In Binary, it is `‭0001 0100 0001 1101 1101 0111 0110 0000 0000 0000`‬. Since the literal values are of type integer, only the 32 LSB will be taken. the overflow will be discarded. So the value would be `0001 1101 1101 0111 0110 0000 0000 0000`, which is `500,654,080` in decimal. So this would be your a value. Your b value is `86,400,000`. No overflows. So now `500,654,080/86,400,000 = 5` is what you get.

If you want the correct solution to your problem, declare the first literal as a `long` so

`a = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000`

will give you the expected output.